# How to enable JDBC/MySqlConnectorj connection pooling?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am still newbish to java development as I am mainly a C# developer. I'd like to know how to use or enable connection pooling when I do SQL requests from my Java servlet.

In C# using the MySql connector, it's super simple as it is only a parameter or two to add in the connection string:

```
Pooling=true; Connection Lifetime=1200;
```

But how does that work in Java? Is it enabled by default?

I am using the "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" driver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a connection pool such as [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html) or [Apache Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/)

Comment: Alright, I'll go with Apache Commons DBCP. Thanks for the suggestions!